# Best way to build multi screen/window app for emergency services with huge amount of data

Tags: angular, reactjs, google-chrome

I have a “best practice” question. I work in an emergency center.

We have an old windows application that works on 3 screens for each worker. The screens show live data, and tons of it. Ambulances, choppers, jeeps, motorcycles.. everything.

2 screens show tons of lists, coordinates, and specific details on all active events or active force.

The 3rd screen shows a map with all of the icons of every element. This is also being updated live every few seconds. Clicking on every icon will also start a live video of the vehicle. This is a paid service of google maps and another company.. it’s also amazing buy heavy.

Lately we’re having some serious UI and graphics issues. The server works great but the rendering is too much for these computers.

We’re thinking of using the same (again, great and fast) server and move the app to Chrome. Making it a web application.
Making it ”webby” will also allow us to provide the ability to see the app in three tablets on the field when there’s a massive event.

We started using Angular and we know and understand that our work could take a very very long time to complete.

My question to the experts here is: how would you do it??

And if we a have a multi window Angular/React app, is it ok for it to have one instance on a single computer, or does it need an instance for each screen on that computer?

Another question: do you think Chrome can handle it?

Comment: Sure thing crome can handle it as long the machines itself arn't that weak. Regarding your multiscreen/pages issue. Your whole setup seems to perfectly fit an electron app with multiple windows.